# How do I forward a complete email without downloading attachments?

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, imap, forward

Hello (and thanks in advance!)

I'm working in Python and I got IMAP and SMTP to work with my Gmail account.
I now need to forward select messages to another account (after reading their body).

How do I do this without downloading the attachments and recreating the entire message?

Thanks!

Tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the IMAP and SMTP Lemonade extensions.  There is support for forwarding messages without downloading.  It's a very new extension, so not many IMAP servers support it yet; I'm not sure if Gmail is one of them.

Section 2 of [RFC 4550](ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc4550.txt) contains the technical details on how this works.